# Setting programming font in RHEL 5 + gvim

Tags: rhel, vim, fonts, gvim

I am working on RedHat RHEL5. I want to change the font in GVIM.

The only font format that my GVIM accepts is

```
*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-m-*-*
```

It refuses to use `Courier\ New` or `Courier_New` names.

The default font is ugly and I wanted to change it to something prettier, like `monospace` font that I use in my terminal, but `xfontsel` does not show his font. `set guifont=*` neither works.

My questions are:

1. How to "convince" GVIM to accept other system fonts
2. Or, how to install additional fonts so they can be delivered to GVIM in `-*-*-*-` Morse code format

**Edit**

`:set guifont=*` gives error:

```
Font "*" is not fixed-width
Invalid font(s): guifont=*
```

To make the font selectable with `xfontsel`, additionally I had to use [this trick](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_and_use_X-Windows_fonts):

```
xset fp+ ~/.fonts/  # maybe unnecessary
xset fp rehash
fc-cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial that shows how to install a custom font in your home directory, in a `.fonts` directory. The tutorial is titled: [installing fonts in your home directory on Fedora 12](http://tacticalvim.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/installing-fonts-in-your-home-directory-on-fedora-12/).

Once a custom font has been installed here you can use the pull downs in `gvim` to change the font or run the command:

```
:set guifont=*
```

Which will bring up the dialog for selecting your font in `gvim`. See [this tutorial on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font) for doing this as well and making them permanent.

I'd suggest the [Proggy Fonts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/The_perfect_programming_font) if you want something that looks good and fits nicely with doing development.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the font but I cannot set it in GVIM (edited question)

Comment: I had to to rehash and eventually it worked (described in my question)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use `vim` in a terminal and set whatever font your terminal offers. The advantage is that you can then run the editor in a terminal multiplexer (e.g. `tmux` or `screen`) and connect to your editing session remotely.

Comment: well,  I would not call it alternative, rather a default option :) It would be sufficient, but the terminal vim has *ugly* colour schemes (yes, I installed *solarized* etc, but my terminal refuses to run 256 colours for some reason)

Comment: What terminal do you use? The problem can bite you in other places as well, so it might be wise to spend some time on that.